# Passing arguments to a backbone view

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, view

Just getting started with Backbone. I have a generic view that can render a collection as a list with a title. I'm currently passing the collection and title into the render method, but that seems a bit odd. Is there another way that's more canonical?

E.g.:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template([
        "<div>",
        "<% if (title) { %><h2><%= title %></h2> <% } %>",
        "<% if (items.length > 0) { %>",
        "<ul>",
            "<% items.each(function(item) { %>",
            "<%= itemTemplate(item) %>",
            "<% }); %>",
        "</ul>",
        "<% } else { %><p>None.</p><% } %>",
        "</div>"
    ].join('')),

    itemTemplate: _.template(
        "<li><%= attributes.name %> (<%= id %>)</li>"
    ),

    render: function(items, title) {
        var html = this.template({
            items: items /* a collection */,
            title : title || '',
            itemTemplate: this.itemTemplate
        });

        $(this.el).append(html);
    }
});

var myView = new ListView({ el: $('#target') });
myView.render(myThings, 'My Things');
myView.render(otherThings, 'Other Things');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should pass attributes in the `initialize()` function:

```
initialize: function (attrs) {
    this.options = attrs;
}
```

So here you would pass the attributes as an object, like so:

```
new MyView({
  some: "something",
  that: "something else"
})
```

Now you have the values that you passed in accessible throughout this instance, in this.options

```
console.log(this.options.some) # "something"
console.log(this.options.that) # "something else"
```

To pass in a collection, I recommend making one parent view and one subview:

```
var View;
var Subview;

View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        try {
            if (!(this.collection instanceof Backbone.Collection)) {
                throw new typeError("this.collection not instanceof Backbone.Collection")
            }
            this.subViews = [];
            this.collection.forEach(function (model) {
                this.subViews.push(new SubView({model: model}));
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        this.subViews.forEach(function (view) {
            this.$el.append(view.render().$el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        try {
            if (!(this.model instanceof Backbone.model)) {
                throw new typeError("this.collection not instanceof Backbone.Collection")
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return this;
    }
});

testCollection = new MyCollection();
collectionView = new View({collection: testCollection});
$("body").html(collectionView.render().$el);
```

You should *always* handle the Models of a Collection, not just the data of the collection.

Comment: I guess with this approach, I'm creating a new view for each collection, rather than reusing the same view with multiple collections. Makes sense.

Comment: Actually... if I'm just passing in some options on instantiation, I don't think I even need to create the initialize method -- it automatically puts the options passed in to the constructor in an options object.

Comment: And then, if I don't want to create a new view for each collection, I can do myViewInstance.options.some = 'New Value'...

Comment: This method is for passing in options, nothing more. If your are passing in a collection, if is more efficient to make one View for the collection itself, and a subview for each model within that collection.

Comment: I have added to the answer the way you should handle Collections and their views

Comment: I'm confused: why are you building views out of Backbone.Model and not Backbone.View?

Comment: Typo, meant to use `Backbone.View`

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Creating a whole subView class just to display <li>item.name</li> seems like overkill to me, but I get where you're going, and that certainly makes sense for a more complicated case.

Comment: Trust me, this is the most efficient way to write views for Collections. This way, you can delegate the `events` object of the `SubView` specific to _that_ model. For every dynamic View, there should always be a model.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a **model** for your **view** and access model's properties when rendering the view.

```
var myModel = new Backbone.Model();

myModel.set("myThings", myThings);
myModel.set("myOtherThings", myOtherThings);

var myView = new ListView({ model: myModel });
```

Comment: This is a view of a collection of models. I suppose I could have a wrapper model around the collection, but that seems like unnecessary structure.

Comment: You can pass a model and a collection at the same time.

Comment: how to access the model inside the view. Is it this.model. I am asking this because for example if I pass: ListView({soption:true,model:myModel}), then I can access soption using: this.options.soption but would then model also be accessible using this.options....?

Comment: Answering my own comments: the model can be accessed using this.options.model inside the backbone view.